# Spring RestTemplate: SSL handshake failure

Tags: spring, authentication, ssl, basic-authentication, resttemplate

I am trying to consume a restful ws with basic auth. I did not import any cert into my keystore. When I use chrome plugin `Advance Rest client` to test it (using basic auth with base64 encoded username:pass). I can see the response back. So far so good.
But when I develop Java code to consume this ws, I get SSL handsake failure:

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error: 
Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:453)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:377)
at test.Rest.main(Rest.java:37) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
```

My question is: if the problem is because I did not import cert to my keystore, then both Java code and plugin should not work together. Here, plugin works but my code does not.
What is the reason? There is somethings wrong with my code?

Bellow is my code

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();         
 String plainCreds = "username:pass"; 
 byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII") );     
 byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes); 
 String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);

 HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders(); 
 headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);

 ResponseEntity<String> response =  
          restTemplate.exchange("https://url",HttpMethod.GET,new  
                                  HttpEntity(headers),String.class);
```

Here is the link to log file:(I have replace my server-name by XXXXXX)
http://www.filedropper.com/ssllog

After running: openssl s_client -showcerts -tls1 -connect host:port

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
CONNECTED(00000164)
8088:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number:.\ssl\s3_pkt.c:362:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 5 bytes and written 0 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : 0000
    Session-ID:
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key:
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1452011344
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

and this is the output when i run command openssl s_client -connect server:port

```
WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf
CONNECTED(00000164)
depth=0 C = US, ST = "XXXXXX", L = XXXXXX, O = XXXXXX, OU = xxxxx, CN = XXXXXXXXX.test.intranet, emailAddress = xxxxx@xxxxx
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = US, ST = "XXXXXXX ", L = XXXXX, O = XXXXXX, OU = xxxxxx, CN = XXXXXXXXX.test.intranet, emailAddress = xxxxx@xxxxx
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=XXXXXXX /L=XXXXX/O=XXXXXX/OU=XXXXX/CN=XXXXXX.test.intranet/emailAddress=xxxxx@xxxxx
   i:/DC=intranet/DC=xxxx/CN=XXXXXX DEV Issuing CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXX.....
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=XXXXXXX /L=XXXXX/O=XXXXXX/OU=XXXXX/CN=XXXXXX.test.intranet/emailAddress=xxxxx@xxxxx
issuer=/DC=intranet/DC=XXX/CN=XXXXX DEV Issuing CA
---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Server Temp Key: XXXXX, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 1895 bytes and written 443 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: 568BF22A5CDBF103155264BBC056B272168AE0777CBC10F055705EB2DD907E5A
    Session-ID-ctx:
    Master-Key: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1452012074
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)
---
read:errno=0
```

Comment: Chrome and your app might use different Java and so have different settings. Even if Java is same there are million reasons why it does not work. However it is good start that it works from Chrome. Enable SSL debug of JVM, e.g: add `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:verbose` and add  output into your question, Additional debug arguments are available here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug

Comment: I would investigate your server, because the log does not contain ` ServerHello` message as if your server wasn’t running SSL. If you have openssl try to connect there with `openssl s_client -showcerts -tls1 -connect [your_host]:[port]`.  Also see http://www.smartjava.org/content/how-analyze-java-ssl-errors

Comment: Thanks Michal. I have added output for running openssl. Please help me. I am new to ssl and certificate stuff

Comment: I thing you ommited `-tls1` openssl switch. Post output with that option on.

Comment: i have posted 2 output: one is with openssl s_client -showcerts -tls1 -connect host:port.      Another one is with openssl s_client -connect server:port.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not notice it on mobile phone screen. Your java client is using tls1 while it is not supported by the server. Let's see how to change the client.

Comment: Strange thing is that JVM chose to use tls1 instead of other, better, version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From `javax.net.debug` log I can see that you are using Java 7 and the client resolves to TLSv1. From `openssl` output that your server does not support TLSv1.

[TLS ver. 1.1 and 1.2 are disabled in Java 7 by default.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/SunProviders.html#tlsprotonote)

> Although SunJSSE in the Java SE 7 release supports TLS 1.1 and TLS
>   1.2, neither version is enabled by default for client connections. Some servers do not implement forward compatibility correctly and
>   refuse to talk to TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 clients. For interoperability,
>   SunJSSE does not enable TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2 by default for client
>   connections.

Enable TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 either by:

1. JVM argument:

   ```
   -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
   ```
2. Or set the same property from Java code:

   ```
   System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1");
   ```
3. Or install [JCE Unlimited Strength policy files for Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html). I am not 100% sure if this single step would solve the problem although it is always worth to install JCE while it allows JVM to use stronger versions of existing algorithms.

**UPDATE 29/Sep/2016**:

Order of protocols changed from better to worse (TLS ver. 1.2 to 1) in options 1 and 2.

Comment: Thanks Michal for your patient to help me. We find out that the server that hosts rest ws is using jdk8, and my client is using jdk7. So we have downgrade server to jdk7. And i also have to force jdk to use TSLv1.2 by using -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2. It is working now.

Comment: before trying to use -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2. i also tried to install JCE Unlimited Strength policy for jdk7. I have replaced files in jdk/jre/lib/security by the files in zip file. But it does not works.

Comment: You are welcome David and thank you for your feedback and appreciation.

Comment: I would turn around the order like this -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1 This way it will try the better protocols first and fall back to v1 at the end.

Answer (score 5):

If you happen to be using Java 7 you need to explicitly tell Java to use TLSv1.2 protocol. Here is an example using Spring XML configuration.

```
***In any Spring bean (i.e. a controller)***

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

@Bean(name="client")
public HttpClient make() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
            new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"}, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .build();
}

***In XML configuration files***

<bean id="factory"
      class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
    <property name="httpClient" ref="client"/>
</bean>
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
    <property name="requestFactory" ref="factory"/>
</bean>
```

You could do the same without XML with something like this:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate;

public HttpClient getHttpClient() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().build();
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
            new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1"}, null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier());
    return HttpClients.custom()
            .setSSLSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory)
            .build();
}

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate(
            new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(
                    getHttpClient()));
    ...
}
```