# Error even after ignoring ssl issues: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: ssl

I'm facing a strange issue. While developing an application, I'm using spring social to provide login with a Facebook account to a user. I'm ignoring certificate check for now using a script for ssl as shown below. The problem is that when I try to get access to the token from Facebook, this script works but when i try to access a user profile, it throws an error

> sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I also tried to create a self signed certificate for my localhost and add it in my java keystore but nothing helps.

Facebook Controller.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/social/facebook")
@Component
public class FacebookController<FacebookApi> {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory
            .getLogger(FacebookController.class);

    private static final String PUBLISH_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String FACEBOOK = "facebook";


    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactoryRegistry connectionFactoryRegistry;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2Parameters oAuth2Parameters;


    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("facebookServiceProvider")
    private OAuthServiceProvider<FacebookApi> facebookServiceProvider;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/signin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView signin(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Redirecting to Facebook.........");
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
        System.setProperty( "http.proxyPort", "80" );
        System.setProperty( "https.proxyPort", "80" );
        System.setProperty( "http.proxyHost", "10.68.248.98" );
        System.setProperty( "https.proxyHost", "10.68.248.98" );

        FacebookConnectionFactory facebookConnectionFactory = (FacebookConnectionFactory) connectionFactoryRegistry
                .getConnectionFactory(FACEBOOK);
        OAuth2Operations oauthOperations = facebookConnectionFactory
                .getOAuthOperations();
        oAuth2Parameters.setState("recivedfromfacebooktoken");
        String authorizeUrl = oauthOperations.buildAuthorizeUrl(
                GrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE, oAuth2Parameters);
        RedirectView redirectView = new RedirectView(authorizeUrl, true, true,
                true);
        System.out.println("Redirecting to Facebook again.........");
        return new ModelAndView(redirectView);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/callback", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void postOnWall(@RequestParam("code") String code,
            @RequestParam("state") String state, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        OAuthService oAuthService = facebookServiceProvider.getService();
        System.out.println(oAuthService.getVersion());
        Verifier verifier = new Verifier(code);
        getSSL();
        Token accessToken =oAuthService.getAccessToken(Token.empty(), verifier);
        //System.out.println(accessToken);
        //System.out.println(accessToken.getToken());
        //getSSL();
        FacebookTemplate template = new FacebookTemplate(accessToken.getToken());
        //System.out.println(template);

        **// ERROR COMES HERE**

        User facebookProfile = template.userOperations().getUserProfile();
        //System.out.println(facebookProfile);
        String userId = facebookProfile.getId();
        //System.out.println(facebookProfile.getEmail());
        //System.out.println(facebookProfile.getFirstName());

        LOGGER.info("Logged in User Id : {}", userId);
        response.sendRedirect("/j_spring_security_check?j_username="+userId);
        //return "success";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/callback", params = "error_reason", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public void error(@RequestParam("error_reason") String errorReason,
            @RequestParam("error") String error,
            @RequestParam("error_description") String description,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        try {
            LOGGER.error(
                    "Error occurred while validating user, reason is : {}",
                    errorReason);
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, description);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void getSSL(){
        SSLContext sslContext=null;
        try {
            sslContext= SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

            // set up a TrustManager that trusts everything
            sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    System.out.println("getAcceptedIssuers =============");
                    return null;
                }

                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkClientTrusted =============");
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs,
                        String authType) {
                    System.out.println("checkServerTrusted =============");
                }
            } }, new SecureRandom());
        } catch (KeyManagementException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(sslContext!=null){
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(
                    sslContext.getSocketFactory());

            HttpsURLConnection
            .setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                public boolean verify(String arg0, SSLSession arg1) {
                    System.out.println("hostnameVerifier =============");
                    return true;
                }
            });

        }
    }

}
```

Error:

```
Redirecting to Facebook.........

D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\jre

Redirecting to Facebook again.........

2.0

checkServerTrusted =============

getAcceptedIssuers =============

Jul 22, 2016 7:50:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring-dispatcher] in context with path [/CIPlatform] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=id%2Cabout%2Cage_range%2Cbio%2Cbirthday%2Ccontext%2Ccover%2Ccurrency%2Cdevices%2Ceducation%2Cemail%2Cfavorite_athletes%2Cfavorite_teams%2Cfirst_name%2Cgender%2Chometown%2Cinspirational_people%2Cinstalled%2Cinstall_type%2Cis_verified%2Clanguages%2Clast_name%2Clink%2Clocale%2Clocation%2Cmeeting_for%2Cmiddle_name%2Cname%2Cname_format%2Cpolitical%2Cquotes%2Cpayment_pricepoints%2Crelationship_status%2Creligion%2Csecurity_settings%2Csignificant_other%2Csports%2Ctest_group%2Ctimezone%2Cthird_party_id%2Cupdated_time%2Cverified%2Cvideo_upload_limits%2Cviewer_can_send_gift%2Cwebsite%2Cwork": sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target] with root cause
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:275)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.upgrade(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:167)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.upgrade(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:329)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:398)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
    at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:91)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2RequestInterceptor.intercept(OAuth2RequestInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.executeInternal(BufferingClientHttpRequestWrapper.java:56)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
    at org.springframework.social.oauth2.OAuth2RequestInterceptor.intercept(OAuth2RequestInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:85)
    at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:69)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
    at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:596)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:572)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:225)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookTemplate.fetchObject(FacebookTemplate.java:220)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:53)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.UserTemplate.getUserProfile(UserTemplate.java:49)
    at com.tools.infosys.ciplatform.servlets.FacebookController.postOnWall(FacebookController.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:858)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:843)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally get it working on my side.

**1.** I had to import the Facebook Graph SSL certificate into my server keystore.

- Go to https://graph.facebook.com and download the certificate as a base 64 file.
- Import the certificate to your keystore. Default keystore password is `changeit`.

**Keytool command:**

```
keytool -import -alias star.facebook.com -keystore <JRE_HOME>\lib\security\cacerts -file star.facebook.com
```

**2.** It appears that the JVM may be using an unsupported TLS version. Since I have the openJDK on GNU/Linux, the JCE Unlimited Strength is already present. No need to do something here.

- If you don't have it (e.g. OracleJDK), you can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html).
- If you prefer, you can set JVM parameters instead:

**Command line**

```
java -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1 ...
```

**System parameters**

```
System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1");
```

**3.** Spring Social 2.0.3.RELEASE will not work properly for the retrieving of user profiles if trying to access the Graph API v2.8 due to deprecated fields ("bio").

**Rather than...**

```
User userProfile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile(); // Error
```

**... use this:**

```
String [] fields = { "id", "email", "first_name", "last_name" };

User userProfile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
```

---

**All references:**

- [PKIK path building failed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36427118/7709086)
- [SSL handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34620092/7709086)
- [Bio field is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39902266/7709086)