# Error message is (#12) bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher

Tags: spring-social-facebook

I used version 2.0.3.RELEASE of spring-social-facebook and Facebook app api v2.8.
I called Facebook login but returned this message.
"(#12) bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher"
How can i fix this?

Comment: There is a PR waiting merge to fix this issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/pull/218

Comment: Any idea when the fix would go through? It's still stuck there at 2.0.3

Comment: The PR has been merged. There is the [v3.0.0.M1](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-facebook/releases/tag/v3.0.0.M1) release available now.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I got the same error,  2.0.3.RELEASE of spring-social-facebook seems to be not compatible with v2.8 Facebook API version (released yesterday). Reading from facebook changelog for the v2.8 (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog):

*User Bios - The bio field on the User object is no longer available. If the bio field was set for a person, the value will now be appended to the about field.*

I think we have to wait a new release of spring-social-facebook library. In the release 2.0.3 (in the interface org.springframework.social.facebook.api.UserOperations) there is the "bio" field in the PROFILE_FIELDS constant and it is not supported in the v2.8 facebook API version.

UPDATE: I found a workaround in my case:

BEFORE:

```java
Connection<Facebook> connection = facebookConnectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
Facebook facebook = connection.getApi();
User userProfile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile();//raises the exception caused by the "bio" field.
```

AFTER

```java
Connection<Facebook> connection = facebookConnectionFactory.createConnection(accessGrant);
Facebook facebook = connection.getApi();
String [] fields = { "id", "email",  "first_name", "last_name" };
User userProfile = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
```

Here a complete list of field you could use:

```
{ "id", "about", "age_range", "birthday", "context", "cover", "currency", "devices", "education", "email", "favorite_athletes", "favorite_teams", "first_name", "gender", "hometown", "inspirational_people", "installed", "install_type", "is_verified", "languages", "last_name", "link", "locale", "location", "meeting_for", "middle_name", "name", "name_format", "political", "quotes", "payment_pricepoints", "relationship_status", "religion", "security_settings", "significant_other", "sports", "test_group", "timezone", "third_party_id", "updated_time", "verified", "video_upload_limits", "viewer_can_send_gift", "website", "work"}
```

Comment: I'm getting following error for above, any suggestions? {"errors":["com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException","Can not construct instance of org.springframework.social.connect.UserProfile: no suitable constructor found, can not deserialize from Object value (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to add/enable type information?)\n at [Source: java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@fa18e2e; line: 1, column: 2]"]}

Comment: This solution is a great replacement for `facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile()` method without any parameter. But how to do the same thing when we want to fetch user object for some other profile id? For example, how to do the same thing for `facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile("some_facebook_id_here")`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/44872810/2015311 for another approach to this issue which will work in all scenarios.

Comment: I don't get it - where is this code you're showing supposed to go? I'm following [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-social/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/htmlsingle/) and I'm getting the same error - but where do you make this particular change in your code?

Comment: You can find the spring-social-facebook current docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/). In the [3.1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-social-facebook/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#retrieving-a-user-s-profile-data) section there is the code that raises the error if you use 2.0.3.RELEASE of spring-social-facebook and facebook app api version >=v2.8.

Answer (score 29):

Workaround for [JHipster](https://jhipster.github.io/). Add the following snippet into your `SocialService` class until `spring-social-facebook` is fixed.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.Modifier;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    try {
        String[] fieldsToMap = { "id", "about", "age_range", "birthday",
                "context", "cover", "currency", "devices", "education",
                "email", "favorite_athletes", "favorite_teams",
                "first_name", "gender", "hometown", "inspirational_people",
                "installed", "install_type", "is_verified", "languages",
                "last_name", "link", "locale", "location", "meeting_for",
                "middle_name", "name", "name_format", "political",
                "quotes", "payment_pricepoints", "relationship_status",
                "religion", "security_settings", "significant_other",
                "sports", "test_group", "timezone", "third_party_id",
                "updated_time", "verified", "viewer_can_send_gift",
                "website", "work" };

        Field field = Class.forName(
                "org.springframework.social.facebook.api.UserOperations")
                .getDeclaredField("PROFILE_FIELDS");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiers = field.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiers.setAccessible(true);
        modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, fieldsToMap);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Source: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2349 - minus `bio` in `fieldsToMap` array.

Comment: looks like my code is getting copied all over the internet :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/34133450/1943228

Answer (score 11):

This has been fixed in new release of spring-social-facebook. Please add the following to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0.M1</version>
</dependency>
```

If you get error that this version is not available, add the following as well.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>alfresco-public</id>
        <url>https://artifacts.alfresco.com/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: Thanks for this...How about the Event operations? Would you have any knowledge.

org.springframework.social.UncategorizedApiException: (#12) is_date_only field is deprecated for versions v2.4 and higher]

Comment: This no longer works for me. I had to use the spring milestone repository:

Comment: See this post for additional dependencies needed to get ConnectionRepository again with 3.0.0.M1 http://stackoverflow.com/a/42175408/1410212

Answer (score 7):

```
package hello;

import  org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import  org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import  org.springframework.social.facebook.api.PagedList;
import  org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Post;
import  org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User;
import  org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import  org.springframework.ui.Model;
import  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import  org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    private Facebook facebook;
    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    public HelloController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }
        String [] fields = { "id","name","birthday","email","location","hometown","gender","first_name","last_name"};
        User user = facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
        String name=user.getName();
        String birthday=user.getBirthday();
        String email=user.getEmail();
        String gender=user.getGender();
        String firstname=user.getFirstName();
        String lastname=user.getLastName();
        model.addAttribute("name",name );
        model.addAttribute("birthday",birthday );
        model.addAttribute("email",email );
        model.addAttribute("gender",gender);
        model.addAttribute("firstname",firstname);
        model.addAttribute("lastname",lastname);
        model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields));
        PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", feed);
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

Comment: How did you get those field data back? I only can get the name, first name and last name, anything else is null. I especially need to have friend data back. So, it is null as well.

Answer (score 5):

I had problems with the new version of spring-social-facebook. To fix this using version 2.0.3.RELEASE paste the following code in your *SocialService.java*

```
@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    try {
        String[] fieldsToMap = {
            "id", "about", "age_range", "birthday", "context", "cover", "currency", "devices", "education", "email", "favorite_athletes", "favorite_teams", "first_name", "gender", "hometown", "inspirational_people", "installed", "install_type","is_verified", "languages", "last_name", "link", "locale", "location", "meeting_for", "middle_name", "name", "name_format","political", "quotes", "payment_pricepoints", "relationship_status", "religion", "security_settings", "significant_other","sports", "test_group", "timezone", "third_party_id", "updated_time", "verified", "viewer_can_send_gift","website", "work"
        };

        Field field = Class.forName("org.springframework.social.facebook.api.UserOperations").
                getDeclaredField("PROFILE_FIELDS");
        field.setAccessible(true);

        Field modifiers = field.getClass().getDeclaredField("modifiers");
        modifiers.setAccessible(true);
        modifiers.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);
        field.set(null, fieldsToMap);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code will not try to retrieve *bio* field from Facebook.

You can see more details here: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/2349

Comment: Super! This works perfectly fine. And I think this should be the appropriate answer to this question as this not only fixes the issue only for one scenario of `facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile()` but all other issues due to the `bio` field being discontinued. Thanks for the solution!

Answer (score 1):

Under grails spring security facebook I had a similar issue and 
thanks to @user6904265 I have managed to get it working:

```
//This was provided example method:
//org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User fbProfile = facebook.userOperations().userProfile
//This is the groovy way of declaring fields:
String[] fields = ['id',"email", "age_range", "birthday","first_name",
                    "last_name","gender"]  as String[]
//This bit pay attention to the User.class segment. 
org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User fbProfile = 
facebook.fetchObject("me", 
org.springframework.social.facebook.api.User.class, fields)
```

Basically the default provided example above states `User.class`. This running locally was unable to find fields such as last_name etc and gave a list it could query. Those provided options were from the actual spring security User class (default to my app) so ensure you also look up correct user classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
FacebookTemplate template = new FacebookTemplate(access_token); 
String [] fields = { "id", "email",  "first_name", "last_name" };
User profile = template.fetchObject("me", User.class, fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

remove the parameter ->"bio" from your api call url, for me it solved

before
                 "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/?fields=name,picture,work,website,religion,location,locale,link,cover,age_range,bio,birthday,devices,email,first_name,last_name,gender,hometown,is_verified,languages&access_token="

after

"https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/me/?fields=name,picture,work,website,religion,location,locale,link,cover,age_range,birthday,devices,email,first_name,last_name,gender,hometown,is_verified,languages&access_token="

Answer (score 0):

I copied interface **UserOperations** in my project changing **PROFILE_FIELDS** removing **bio** field. On Tomcat, my edited class takes priority over org.springframework.social.facebook.api.UserOperations interface and this fix the problem. (see last rows of below file)

```
/*
 * Copyright 2015 the original author or authors.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
package org.springframework.social.facebook.api;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.social.ApiException;
import org.springframework.social.MissingAuthorizationException;
public interface UserOperations {

/**
 * Retrieves the profile for the authenticated user.
 * @return the user's profile information.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 * @throws MissingAuthorizationException if FacebookTemplate was not created with an access token.
 */
User getUserProfile();

/**
 * Retrieves the profile for the specified user.
 * @param userId the Facebook user ID to retrieve profile data for.
 * @return the user's profile information.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 */
User getUserProfile(String userId);

/**
 * Retrieves the user's profile image. Returns the image in Facebook's "normal" type.
 * @return an array of bytes containing the user's profile image.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 * @throws MissingAuthorizationException if FacebookTemplate was not created with an access token.
 */
byte[] getUserProfileImage();

/**
 * Retrieves the user's profile image. Returns the image in Facebook's "normal" type.
 * @param userId the Facebook user ID.
 * @return an array of bytes containing the user's profile image.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 */
byte[] getUserProfileImage(String userId);

/**
 * Retrieves the user's profile image.
 * @param imageType the image type (eg., small, normal, large. square)
 * @return an array of bytes containing the user's profile image.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 * @throws MissingAuthorizationException if FacebookTemplate was not created with an access token.
 */
byte[] getUserProfileImage(ImageType imageType);

/**
 * Retrieves the user's profile image.
 * @param userId the Facebook user ID.
 * @param imageType the image type (eg., small, normal, large. square)
 * @return an array of bytes containing the user's profile image.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 */
byte[] getUserProfileImage(String userId, ImageType imageType);

/**
 * Retrieves the user's profile image. When height and width are both used,
 * the image will be scaled as close to the dimensions as possible and then
 * cropped down.
 * @param width the desired image width
 * @param height the desired image height
 * @return an array of bytes containing the user's profile image.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 */
byte[] getUserProfileImage(Integer width, Integer height);

/**
 * Retrieves the user's profile image. When height and width are both used,
 * the image will be scaled as close to the dimensions as possible and then
 * cropped down.
 * @param userId the Facebook user ID.
 * @param width the desired image width
 * @param height the desired image height
 * @return an array of bytes containing the user's profile image.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 */
byte[] getUserProfileImage(String userId, Integer width, Integer height);

/**
 * Retrieves a list of permissions that the application has been granted for the authenticated user.
 * @return the permissions granted for the user.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 * @throws MissingAuthorizationException if FacebookTemplate was not created with an access token.
 */
List<Permission> getUserPermissions();

/**
 * Fetches IDs that the user has on any applications associated with the calling application via Facebook's Business Mapping API.
 * @return a list of ID-to-application mapping that the user has on related applications.
 */
List<UserIdForApp> getIdsForBusiness();

/**
 * Fetches a list of places that the user has checked into or has been tagged at.
 * @return a list of place tags for the user.
 */
List<PlaceTag> getTaggedPlaces();

/**
 * Searches for users.
 * @param query the search query (e.g., "Michael Scott")
 * @return a list of {@link Reference}s, each representing a user who matched the given query.
 * @throws ApiException if there is an error while communicating with Facebook.
 * @throws MissingAuthorizationException if FacebookTemplate was not created with an access token.
 */
PagedList<Reference> search(String query);

static final String[] PROFILE_FIELDS = {
    "id", "about", "age_range",/*"bio",*/ "birthday", "context", "cover", "currency", "devices", "education", "email", 
    "favorite_athletes", "favorite_teams", "first_name", "gender", "hometown", "inspirational_people", "installed", "install_type",
    "is_verified", "languages", "last_name", "link", "locale", "location", "meeting_for", "middle_name", "name", "name_format", 
    "political", "quotes", "payment_pricepoints", "relationship_status", "religion", "security_settings", "significant_other", 
    "sports", "test_group", "timezone", "third_party_id", "updated_time", "verified", "video_upload_limits", "viewer_can_send_gift", 
    "website", "work"
};
```

}