# Kentico Facebook API OATH issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api, kentico

Kentico V9.0.44 seems to be giving errors using the Facebook Login feature.  We are using the Login As Facebook and Register as Facebook feature. The issue is happening on the site and also on the "Goat" demo ecommerce site from Kentico.  Does anyone have suggestions?

```html
Message: Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown.

Exception type: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException Stack Trace: at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Message: (OAuthException - #12) (#12) bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher

Exception type: Facebook.FacebookOAuthException Stack Trace: at Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags) at Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) at Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) at CMS.MembershipProvider.Facebook.FacebookUserProvider.GetFacebookUser(String facebookUserId, String accessToken) at CMSWebParts_Membership_FacebookConnect_FacebookConnectLogon.MapFacebookUserProfile(FacebookUserProfileMappingTriggerEnum mappingTrigger, UserInfo user, String userProfileId, String facebookAccessToken) at CMSWebParts_Membership_FacebookConnect_FacebookConnectLogon.SignInUser(UserInfo ui, String facebookUserId, String facebookAccessToken, Boolean mapFacebookProfile) at CMSWebParts_Membership_FacebookConnect_FacebookConnectLogon.SetupControlForPublicUser() at CMS.PortalControls.CMSWebPartZone.OnContentLoaded() at CMS.PortalControls.CMSAbstractLayout.OnContentLoaded() at CMS.PortalControls.CMSAbstractLayout.LoadWebPartsContent(Boolean reloadData) at CMS.PortalControls.CMSAbstractLayout.LoadContent(PageInfo pageInfo, Boolean reloadData, Boolean allowOrphanedZones) at CMS.PortalControls.CMSPagePlaceholder.LoadContent(PageInfo pageInfo, Boolean reloadData) at CMS.PortalControls.CMSPagePlaceholder.LoadContent(PageInfo pageInfo, Boolean reloadData) at CMS.PortalControls.CMSPortalManager.LoadPage(Boolean reloadData) at CMS.PortalControls.CMSPortalManager.PageHelper_InitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) at CMS.Helpers.PageContext.CurrentPage_InitComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Page.OnInitComplete(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Answer (score 0):

Facebook makes updates to their API all of the time. A similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890885/error-message-is-12-bio-field-is-deprecated-for-versions-v2-8-and-higher) with a fix but you will have to go into the web part code to fix it.