# Using Facebook API older version

Tags: java, spring, facebook-graph-api

I need to get user's friend list, but i'm getting error

```
org.springframework.social.UncategorizedApiException: (#12) bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher
```

I tried to use solution from here: http://en.stack.aiseen.org/questions/39890885/error-message-is-12-bio-field-is-deprecated-for-versions-v2-8-and-higher, but it doesn't work for me, I'm getting same error.

Is there way to override Facebook API version which would be used by spring-social (f.e. in YML)? v2.7 will be available till mid of 2018, I would like to use it. Is it possible?

PS. using 2.0.3.RELEASE version of spring-social-facebook.

Comment: you can only use older versions of the api with an app created before the next api was released

Comment: btw, how to override the api version is explained in the official changelog. but again, you can´t use older versions with a newer app.

Comment: I have the same issue. Look at this SO [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39902266/5676586). It solved the issue.