# What has happened with the class org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository in Spring Social 3.0.0.M1?

Tags: spring, facebook-graph-api, spring-social, spring-social-facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

I am a beginner with the Spring Framework and wanted to try out Spring Social to make a simple web application which retrieves data from Facebook. For this I followed Spring Socials official "*Getting started guide*" called "*Accessing Facebook Data*".

The first problem I encountered was that the Spring Social version **2.0.3.RELEASE**, which seems to be the latest official version of Spring Social, does not support version 2.8 of the facebook API (and therefore gives me the following error: "**(#12) bio field is deprecated for versions v2.8 and higher**"). As I have created the Facebook app at developers.facebook.com yesterday it seems I don't have access to the previous API versions.

I searched with google for a solution and found that version **3.0.0.M1** seems to be available in the maven repository, which is supposed to fix this problem. But when I changed the configuration in my .pom-file to use this version instead the compiler can't find the class **ConnectionRepository** anymore. Actually the whole package **org.springframework.social.connect** seems to be missing.

The code, which I copied from the guide (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/) looks as followig:

```
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.PagedList;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Post;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    private Facebook facebook;
    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    public HelloController(Facebook facebook, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.facebook = facebook;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/facebook";
        }

        model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", feed);
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

Was ConnectionRepository deprecated and now removed? If that is the case should I use something else instead? Or am I missing something?

Just removing all references to ConnectionRepository gives me following error instead when starting the application:

*org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloController': Resolution of declared constructors on bean Class [hello.HelloController] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93] failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/social/ApiBinding*

In this case the code looks as following:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Facebook;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.PagedList;
import org.springframework.social.facebook.api.Post;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {

    private Facebook facebook;

    public HelloController(Facebook facebook) {
        this.facebook = facebook;

    }

    @GetMapping
    public String helloFacebook(Model model) {


        model.addAttribute("facebookProfile", facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile());
        PagedList<Post> feed = facebook.feedOperations().getFeed();
        model.addAttribute("feed", feed);
        return "hello";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking at the git history of the source code for the artifact **spring-social-facebook**, which I got from GitHub, I couldn't find any trace of **ConnectionRepository** at all.

After checking it out at mvnrepository.com I realized that when using version **2.0.3.RELEASE** of the artifact **spring-social-facebook** as a dependency a lot more jar-files where dowloaded by Maven than it was when using version **3.0.0.M1** as a dependency. Among the missing jar-filer were two artifacts which I needed to get my application up and running. They were **spring-social-core** and **spring-social-config**.

In the end I found **ConnectionRepository** in the **spring-social-core** jar-file.

So what I in the end needed to do was to change the dependencies in the original pom-file from the guide, which were the following:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

to:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.M2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

These changes allowed me to start up the application and retrieve some facebook data.

Comment: Very instructive. I found out that 3.0.0.M1 is in the Spring Milestones Repository, so had to add that to my pom first: 
`<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Spring Milestones Repository</id>
      <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone/</url>
    </repository>
 </repositories>`