# kubernetes ingress TLS validation and redirection issue

Tags: rest, http, redirect, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have two environments of kubernetes which use a ingress as a proxy to redirect request to serve the statics (front) and back-end rest services.

Such requests can be accessed by two host URLs in one of the environments (one host has a tls cert secret configured) and in the other environment, I don't have any tls secret configured and it only can be accessed by one host URL

In the first environment (Only one host and without TLS secret) I have the following:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "70"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  creationTimestamp: "XXXX"
  generation: 9
  labels:
    app: myapp
    chart: myapp-0.1.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: myapp-ingress
  name: myapp-ingress
  namespace: myapp-namespace
  resourceVersion: "25745018"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/my-app-namespace/ingresses/my-app-ingress
  uid: 34c3d902-1517
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostOne
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-front
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-backend
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /myappapi/(.+)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hostOne
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

in this one I can perfectly make request through HTTP and everything works fine. For HTTPS request I get an SSLExcepcion because the cert is not installed in the client (This is normal and obvious)

In the second cluster I have TLS secret and two hosts URL:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "70"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  creationTimestamp: "XXXX"
  generation: 9
  labels:
    app: myapp
    chart: myapp-0.1.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: myapp-ingress
  name: myapp-ingress
  namespace: myapp-namespace
  resourceVersion: "25745018"
  selfLink: /apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/my-app-namespace/ingresses/my-app-ingress
  uid: 34c3d902-1517
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostOne
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-front
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-backend
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /myappapi/(.+)
  - host: hostTwo
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-front
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-backend
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /myappapi/(.+)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hostTwo
    secretName: tlsSecret
  - hosts:
    - hostOne
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

In this case when requesting with HTTP I get a 803 error with a redirect to HTTPS in both URLs (hostOne and hostTwo)

I would like to have the redirect when using http only for hostTwo which is the one that is configured with a certificate and TLS secret.

Why the ingress in responding with that redirect for http and in the first case it doesn't? What I should change?

When I send A request with RestTemplate to https I get a SSLException:

```
2020-05-08 12:57:05,586 ERROR class=ExceptionHandler Received fatal alert: handshake_failure; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
```

I tried to install the cert and ad TLS1.2 as explained here:
[Spring RestTemplate: SSL handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34563385/spring-resttemplate-ssl-handshake-failure)

but it did not work and I can't send request with http just to check if the services are well code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it.
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/

just adding 
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false", because the default value it is true.
@nischay, your solution does not work because in the first ingress should be necesary to add nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false" and its more complex to split the ingress than just adding the annotation, 
Anyway thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you have 2 separate `Ingress` objects. One for SSL Host and another one for non-SSL host. Please check the below 2 ingress objects.

**For HostOne - where redirection is not needed**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "70"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
  generation: 9
  labels:
    app: myapp
    chart: myapp-0.1.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: myapp-ingress
  name: myapp-ingress-non-ssl
  namespace: myapp-namespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostOne
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-front
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-backend
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /myappapi/(.+)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hostOne
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```

**For HostTwo - where Redirection is needed #Added the redirection annotation**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "70"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "1000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "1000"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
  generation: 9
  labels:
    app: myapp
    chart: myapp-0.1.0
    heritage: Helm
    release: myapp-ingress
  name: myapp-ingress-ssl
  namespace: myapp-namespace
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostTwo
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-front
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /(.*)
      - backend:
          serviceName: myapp-backend
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /myappapi/(.+)
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - hostTwo
    secretName: tlsSecret
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - {}
```